# Azure logic app returns file content as encoded string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

**I need to pass one Excel file saved in one drive to azure function app using azure logic app**

[image: after trigger logic app it shows like this]

*I created my function app for read excel file it works fine when I send excel file via postman in form-data type*

I tried with 
**base64** **, utf-8** **, utf-16** 
encoding and decoding ways to create excel file inside azure function a
by referring some StackOverflow questions and documentations but I couldn't

**when i use below code**

```
    byte[] fileinbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(file);
    File.WriteAllBytes("abcd.xlsx", fileinbytes);
```

**it throws exception**

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
>   among the padding characters.

**problem is how can decode these string in to file inside my function app or how to read these encoded string as excel file**

Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide your function code about decoding(base64) the string from logic app "Get file content" ?

Comment: @HuryShen i tried with Convert.FromBase64String and  System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode and many other ways but all time it returned another encode string

Comment: @IshwarGagare no brother i need to pass excel sheet to my azure function not for blob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I fixed the Issue

I changed Azure function request from logic app inside **Logic app code view**  feature as below

```
            "body": {
                "file": "@{base64(body('Get_file_content'))}"
            },
```

and now my azure function

```
        string file = req.Query["file"];
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        file = file ?? data?.file;
        byte[] fileinbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(file);
        File.WriteAllBytes("abcd.xlsx", fileinbytes);
```